# batch scripting - environment variables are not set when using pipe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe

I have 2 scripts:

1. set_env_var.bat - sets environment variables if "y" is pressed.
2. install.bat - install my project - depended on set_env_var.bat environment variables.

I'm trying to run those scripts in a single cmd instruction:

```
echo y| set_env_var.bat && install.bat
```

When im running it this way i cant find any of the of the environment variables that set_env_var.bat sets, not from the cmd or install.bat.

i guess set_env_var.bat is launched on new CMD when running it that way...

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: `set_env_var.bat` is a batch file. A batch file must be called from within a batch file with command `call`. So try `(echo y| call "set_env_var.bat") && call "install.bat"`. But you should study the documentation of `set_env_var.bat` or look on its code as it is most likely possible to call this batch file without user prompt by using a specific option. If this batch file does not support an option to avoid the user prompt, you can edit the batch file and comment out the user prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the pipe `|` initiates two new `cmd` instances for either side, and any environment changes eventually become lost.

You could create a "Yes"-file (a text file just containing `y`), then use input redirection:

```cmd
< "yes.txt" "set_env_var.bat" && "install.bat"
```

You could even include its creation and deletion:

```cmd
(echo y) > "yes.txt" && < "yes.txt" "set_env_var.bat" && "install.bat" & del "yes.txt"
```

The parentheses around `echo y` prevent an unintentional trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to be returned.

---

Although it is not absolutely necessary in this particular situation (since all commands are in a single line), you should still follow [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633477/batch-scripting-environment-variables-are-not-set-when-using-pipe#comment114283983_64633477) and use `call` to, well, call a batch file from another to ensure execution returns to the main script, particularly because of proper handling of condition execution (using the operators `&&` and `||`):

```cmd
(echo y) > "yes.txt" && (< "yes.txt" call "set_env_var.bat" && call "install.bat" & del "yes.txt")
```

The parentheses as well as the command concatenation operators (`&`, `&&`) are used intentionally:

- the first pair of parentheses still avoids a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to be written to `yes.txt`;
- the second pair, together with `&&` and `&`, control execution flow:

  - try to create `yes.txt`; only upon success, execute the following command, which is the whole parenthesised remainder;

    - call `set_env_var.bat`;
    - only upon success of `set_env_var.bat`, call `install.bat`;
    - independent on success of the preceding commands, try to delete `yes.txt`;

In this context, success means an exit code of zero, while failure means a non-zero exit code.

Regard, that without using `call` for batch files, the operators `&&` and `||` may lead to unexpected results.